# Importing data from server txt/xml

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml

I'm currently developing an app that will be used as track and trace app. This app will need data that is located on a server. Let's say, we create a file for each customer on the server. This file will contain the track and trace info. Would it be easier if this is a xml file or text file and how would the code look like?

Let's say we've already knew the customers number and the file has the same name as the customer number. The user tapped the button to get the data. Then the app contacts the server asking for the file that got the same customers number and reads it presenting the info in a label or something similar.

Any suggestions where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have any other specific requirements fetching xml files from server will be good enough. For example if you have file at url [www.test.com/user1.xml](http://www.test.com/user1.xml) you can load into data

```
NSData *tmpData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.test.com/user1.xml"] ];
                    //convert data to string
NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tmpData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *piecesArray = [tmpString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
if(piecesArray.count==2)
{
   labelA.text = [piecesArray objectAtIndex:0];
   labelB.text = [piecesArray objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: Ok now in that file we have the date and the status how would i present them to a label? So search the file put the date in lable X and the status in label Y

Comment: Well that depends of data format, xml, csv... whatever, you need to specify format.

Comment: Yes it would, you can parse tmpString, and get the results.

Comment: Ok great, The text file contains these 2 lines:
1301242105 TOMTOM100.

1301242105 would be presented in label A and TOMTOM100 in label B.

Comment: {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf340
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 1301242105 TOMTOM100}

Comment: I`ve edited my answer for simple case. If my answers were helpful please upvote them and mark as correct.

Comment: oke this works semi, i still get all the other info not just the 2. how can i get rid of this:{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf340 {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;} {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;} \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0 \pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx623‌​6\tx6803\pardirnatural \f0\fs24 \cf0

Comment: if(piecesArray.count==3)
{
   labelA.text = [piecesArray objectAtIndex:1];
   labelB.text = [piecesArray objectAtIndex:2];
}
helpful?